# Sorting NSArray using localized dictionary values

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsarray, nssortdescriptor

I can easily sort an array of dictionaries using a sort descriptor like this:

```
    NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name"  ascending:YES];
```

But I am populating a table with the localized string values, which means the sort is no longer correct in that language.

Aside from rebuilding my array of dictionaries with localized values, is there a way to configure the sort descriptor to do this?

I would like to keep the immutable dictionaries in the native language to avoid deep copying and dealing with mutable elements. These dictionaries are derived from JSON representation, and can get deep.

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can use this method:

```
- (id)initWithKey:(NSString *)key ascending:(BOOL)ascending comparator:(NSComparator)cmptr;
```

In the comparator block, you get the localized key of the two dictionaries and compare them:

```
NSComparator comparator= ^NSComparisonResult (id dict1, id dict2)
{
    NSString* str1=[dict1 objectForKey: @"name"];
    NSString* str2=[dict2 objectForKey: @"name"];
    NSString* localizedStr1= NSLocalizedString(str1,str1);
    NSString* localizedStr2= NSLocalizedString(str2, str2);
    return [localizedStr1 compare: localizedStr2];
};
```